# How to access a method of another screen component?

Tags: react-native, velo, wix-react-native-navigation

```
Navigation.registerComponent("LoginScreen", () => LoginScreen);
Navigation.registerComponent("HomeScreen", () => HomeScreen);
```

Inside LoginScreen, after succeeded logging-in I want to call Fetching Data method inside HomeScreen Component.

Comment: In big projects you can use [Redux](https://redux.js.org/), but in small projects, if components are parent-child or sibling you can do this like [this](https://www.javascriptstuff.com/component-communication/)

Comment: Thanks Mohsen, I think I have to use Redux and react-thunk!

Answer (score 1):

If you have something like an API service, you can do a file that exports Promise or whatever that makes requests et use them everywhere

Comment: Exporting class and called in anywhere to update redux states would be great!

Comment: It's the case, checkout Redux and Redux-Thunk. The idea is that you create actions files and you can call those action from your components anywhere. You usually got a service file where you call fetch requests that will populate the store of your app and modify the state of your app. In the end, you can have everything from everywhere. Even without redux, if it's a small app, you can simply do requests in a file, each functions that execute a request returns a promise after the request completion and you can retrieve data in any view ;)